# Local truncation error of Dufort Frankel Scheme

Tags: finite-difference, numerics, error-estimation

The scheme is given by
$$\frac{v_m^{n+1}-v_m^{n-1}}{2k} + b\frac{v_m^{n+1}+v_m^{n-1}-v_{m-1}^n-v_{m+1}^n}{h^2} = 0$$

where $v_m^n$ is the numerical solution at the $m^\text{th}$ spatial coordinate and $n^\text{th}$ time step. It approximates a solution to

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} - b\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} = 0$$

I need to find a bound for the local truncation error. Is there a relatively **quick** way of doing this? I need to do this sort of thing on an exam, and I don't want to take too long, or rush it and make a mistake, possibly taking even longer.

Comment: Taylor series about $v_{m}^{n}$ for each term and collect terms such that the original PDE is on the left and the rest of the terms are on the right. The lowest order terms on the right for each dimension correspond to the local truncation errors.

Comment: I don't think that's right. Because then Euler's method would have a LTE of $O(k)$ even though it has an LTE of $O(k^2)$. Am I missing something?

Comment: When I do what I said for just the first term, the one representing the time derivative, I end up with it being $O(k^2)$, which makes sense since the time scheme is a second order central difference.

Comment: Well, here's the issue. We know that Euler's method has an LTE of $O(k^2)$, but when I do what you said:
$$\frac{y_{n+1} - y_n}{k} = y_n' + O(k)$$
which is not the right answer.

Comment: You're incorrect. Euler's method is $O(k)$. The result you obtained by hand is correct.

Comment: I agree that the order of Euler's method is $O(k)$, but see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method#Local_truncation_error

Comment: The local truncation error is, as shown in that link, just $\text{LTE} = y_{n+1} - y_n$, which if you take the right hand side of your result ends up as: $\text{LTE} = y_{n}^{'}k + O(k^2)$. This means LTE is $O(k^2)$, as expected.

Comment: I want to note I realize in my original comment I wasn't thinking about the local truncation error in my explanation, but just the overall truncation error. Sorry for the mistake. These slides might help explain the added step you'll need to make on top of my suggestion: http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~ms713/lecture_4.pdf

Comment: Truncation error can be confusing unless you realize that it is always relative error. In the Forward Euler method, the error in calculating $y_{n+1}-y_n$ is $O(k^2)$, but the true answer is $O(k)$ so the relative error is $(k)$. Another way of thinking about it is to concern yourself with the error in $dy/dt$.

Answer (score 1):

This can be simplified using the even and odd parts of the function in time and space direction.
\begin{align}
\text{odd: }&v(x,t+k)-v(x,t-k)=2\left[kv_t(x,t)+\frac{k^3}6v_{ttt}+...\right]
\\
\text{even: }&v(x,t+k)+v(x,t-k)=2\left[v(x,t)+\frac{k^2}2v_{tt}+\frac{k^4}{24}v_{tttt}+...\right]
\\
\text{even: }&v(x+h,t)+v(x-h,t)=2\left[v(x,t)+\frac{h^2}2v_{xx}+\frac{h^4}{24}v_{xxxx}+...\right]
\end{align}
Thus the leading error terms are
$$
\frac{k^2}6v_{ttt},~~~\frac{k^2}{2h^2}v_{tt},~~~\frac{h^2}{24}v_{xxxx}
$$
This suggests that one has to select $k\sim h^2$. I do not see that the identity $v_{tt}=b^2v_{xxxx}$ simplifies the error formula.

Answer (score 0):

A similar subject [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/24580/more-smearing-with-decreasing-timestep-in-advection-problems/24588#24588) where I show the way to calculate the truncation error with the advection equation.

A search gives me [this](http://how.gi.alaska.edu/ao/sim/homework/h1311a.pdf). I think that could answer your question ?