# How numerical diffusion is related to advection term?

Tags: numerical-modelling, advection-diffusion

I have crude idea that numerical diffusion arises while using upwind scheme and causes solution to deviate from its original one. But I am unable to understand how numerical diffusion phenomenon is (directly) related to advection phenomenon?

Answer (score 4):

I would like to add that besides the spatial discretization the temporal discretization can also introduce numerical diffusion.

Consider the advection equation $$ u_t + cu_x = 0$$ where I use the subscripts for partial derivatives: $ u_i \equiv \frac{\partial u}{\partial i}$

Applying a general $\theta$-scheme to discretize the temporal derivative yields the semi-discrete formulation:
$$ \frac{u^{(n + 1)} - u^{(n)}}{\Delta t} = - c\Big( \theta u_x^{(n + 1)} + (1 - \theta) u_x^{(n)} \Big) $$ where $\theta \in [0, 1]$ and $n$ denotes the time index which is written in parantheses to distinguish it from powers.
Note that
$$ \theta = \begin{cases} 
0 & \text{Euler Forward} \\
0.5 & \text{Crank-Nicolson} \\
1 & \text{Euler Backward} \\
\end{cases} $$

Now expand $u$ (assuming sufficient regularity) for a fixed $\theta$ around $t^\star \equiv t^{(n)} + \theta \Delta t $ in a Taylor-Series:

$$ 
\begin{align}
u(t^{(n)}) = u^{(n)} =& u(t^\star) + u_t(t^\star) (t^{(n)} - t^\star) + 0.5 u_{tt}(t^\star) (t^{(n)} - t^\star) + \mathcal{O}\big((\Delta t)^3\big) \\
=& u(t^\star) -\theta \Delta t u_t(t^\star) + 0.5 u_{tt}(t^\star) \theta^2 (\Delta t)^2 + \mathcal{O}\big((\Delta t)^3\big)
\end{align}
$$
and
$$ 
\begin{align}
u(t^{(n + 1)}) = u^{(n + 1)} =& u(t^\star) + u_t(t^\star) (t^{(n + 1)} - t^\star) + 0.5 u_{tt}(t^\star) (t^{(n + 1)} - t^\star) + \mathcal{O}\big((\Delta t)^3\big) \\
=& u(t^\star) + (1 - \theta) \Delta t u_t(t^\star) + 0.5 u_{tt}(t^\star) (1 - \theta)^2 (\Delta t)^2 + \mathcal{O}\big((\Delta t)^3\big)
\end{align}
$$

thus
$$ \frac{u^{(n + 1)} - u^{(n)}}{\Delta t} = u_t(t^\star) + 0.5 ( 1- 2 \theta) \Delta t u_{tt}(t^\star) + \mathcal{O}\big((\Delta t)^2\big) $$

At the same time (using the Taylor-Expansions written out above) for the spatial derivative $u_x$ and truncating already after the linear term gives

$$ 
u_x^{(n)} = u_x(t^\star) -\theta \Delta t u_{xt}(t^\star) + \mathcal{O}\big((\Delta t)^2\big)
$$
and
$$ 
u_x^{(n + 1)} = u_x(t^\star) + (1 - \theta) \Delta t u_{xt}(t^\star) + \mathcal{O}\big((\Delta t)^2\big)
$$

and thus

$$ \theta u_x^{(n + 1)} + (1 - \theta) u_x^{(n)} = u_x(t^\star) + \mathcal{O}\big((\Delta t)^2\big) $$

We performed a Taylor Expansion, so let's take a look at the truncation error:
$$ 
\begin{align}
e =& \frac{u^{(n + 1)} - u^{(n)}}{\Delta t} \Bigg|_\text{Taylor} + c\Big( \theta u_x^{(n + 1)} + (1 - \theta) u_x^{(n)} \Big)\Bigg|_\text{Taylor} \\
=& u_t(t^\star) + 0.5 ( 1- 2 \theta) \Delta t u_{tt}(t^\star) + c u_x(t^\star) + \mathcal{O}\big((\Delta t)^2\big) \\
\overset{u_t(t) + cu_x(t) = 0 \: \forall \: t}{=}& (0.5 - \theta) \Delta t u_{tt}(t^\star) + \mathcal{O}\big((\Delta t)^2\big)
\end{align}
$$
Taking the derivative of the original PDE with respect to time yields
$$ u_{tt} + c u_{xt} = 0$$
and noting that
$$u_{xt} = \partial_x u_t = \partial_x (-c u_x) = -c u_{xx} $$
so
$$ 
e = c(-0.5 + \theta) \Delta t u_{xx}(t^\star) + \mathcal{O}\big((\Delta t)^2\big)
$$
so the differential equation that is solved turns out to be
$$ \tilde u_t + c \Big( (\theta - 0.5) \Delta t \tilde u_{xx} + \tilde u_x \Big) = 0$$
This is why the Crank-Nicolson scheme is preferably used when advection-related phenomena are of particular interest, since it causes the $\tilde u_{xx}$ term to vanish.

Answer (score 1):

The numerical diffusion is not related to an equation specifically but is related to **the way you discretize** this equation.

Depending on the discretization stencil you choose (upwind, downwind, centered, hybrid...), you scheme can be diffusive, compressive or dispersive according to the sign and the order of the derivatives involved in the truncation error. You can understand that by deriving and analysing the truncation error through a Taylor expansion, I did an example [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/24580/more-smearing-with-decreasing-timestep-in-advection-problems/24588#24588) where I explain why the advection equation discretized with an upwind scheme produces numerical diffusion.

Answer (score 0):

Consider your advection equation on a uniform grid $$u_j^n\simeq u(j\Delta x,n\Delta t)$$
Every linear numerical method for solving this equation by advancing from time level $n$ to time level $n+1$ does so by some version of the following process. Pick some neighborhood of $j$, say $j-k,\ldots,j+\ell$ and fit some kind of function
$$U(u_{j-k}^n\dots,u_{j+\ell}^n;x)$$ to this data. Then evaluate
$$U(u_{j-k}^n\dots,u_{j+\ell}^n;x-\frac{c\Delta t}{\Delta x})$$
You will find this to be true however the advection scheme is derived and whatever it is called.

Numerically, advection is nothing but interpolation (to the foot of the characteristic line $dx/dt=c$)and you may find the link between interpolation and diffusion more intuitive. Now interpolation sounds easy, but it must be done many, many times, and any fault of your interpolation scheme will be greatly magnified.
To get you started, useful reading is LeVecque R. 1990. Numerical methods for conservation laws. Basel: Birkhauser- Verlag.

Upwinding is a much misunderstood topic. Think of it as centering the stencil on the place that the information comes from (the foot of the characteristic) For a system of equations, different information comes from different places (characteristic equations)